# Spring REST @ResponseStatus with Custom exception class does not change the return Status code

Tags: java, spring-rest

I have a exception class like follows

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, reason="Unprocessable Entity")  // 422
public class UnprocessableEntityException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Now the status is not returned as 422 unless I write a specific handler in the Controller class like :

```
@ExceptionHandler(UnprocessableEntityException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    public String handleException(Exception ex) {
...
}
```

As I understand I should not need @ExceptionHandler in first place, not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing a `@ResponseStatus` annotated exception from a controller method should be enough for the framework to write the HTTP status code - no `@ExceptionHandler` necessary.

The following will write a 422 Status on hitting the webapp root as expected:

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void action() {
        throw new ActionException();
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, reason = "nope")
    public static class ActionException extends RuntimeException {}
}
```

This works courtesy of the `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` which is created by Spring MVC by default - if it's not working for you, my guess is that this default exception resolver has been removed (by e.g. overriding `WebMvcConfigurationSupport.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers` or otherwise configuring your context's `HandlerExceptionResolver`s so that the `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` is trumped.)

Comment: Annotating your custom Exception class with `@ResponseStatus` smells like poor design to me. In general, **your Exception classes should not have platform-specific dependencies**. In my organization we use 422 for business logic errors (e.g., schedule time off in a past date). We throw a custom unchecked exception for those. If you're in a Kafka consumer and detect one such error you may throw that exception. But if it's annotated with `@ResponseStatus` your Kafka consumer program requires a dependency to spring web.  :^(

Comment: I definitely wouldn't advocate throwing exceptions from deep in your business logic with a spring-web dependency, but instead you would translate such exceptions to web-tier specific ones from within your controllers or elsewhere in your web tier.

Comment: Why translate any exception coming from application or domain layer into a REST adapter-specific exception *that you created*?

Comment: Personally I just think this is good design: you probably already convert your domain entities into protocol-specific DTOs. Why not do the same for exceptions? You just need a single annotated exception class with your `422` status, and a tiny amount of code to do the conversion - with a bit of AOP the work to do this everywhere would fall away to almost nothing. Maybe your situation wouldn't get any value out of this approach and you would be better off implementing your own `HandlerExceptionResolver` for example, but I don't think it's necessarily poor design.

Answer (score 1):

The exception thrown should not be handled by code or by other exception resolvers, for example it shouldn't be handled by `@ExceptionHandler`, because that will override the status code specified by the exception class's `@ResponseStatus`.